# List AppxPackages by IsFramework = True

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm working on a PowerShell script that automates AppxPackages uninstallation.

When we type this command: Get-AppxPackage, we get a result like this:

```
PS C:\> Get-AppxPackage

Name              : Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.6
Publisher         : CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
Architecture      : X64
ResourceId        :
Version           : 1.6.24903.0
PackageFullName   : Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.6_1.6.24903.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
InstallLocation   : C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.6_1.6.24903.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
IsFramework       : True
PackageFamilyName : Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.6_8wekyb3d8bbwe
PublisherId       : 8wekyb3d8bbwe
IsResourcePackage : False
IsBundle          : False
IsDevelopmentMode : False
IsPartiallyStaged : False
SignatureKind     : Store
Status            : Ok

#And many more...
```

Look at `IsFramework`.
I want to list all `IsFramework` = `True` AppxPackages.

Right now, I have this code: `Get-AppxPackage | Select Name, IsFramework`

It lists ALL AppxPackages, and I want to list ONLY `IsFramework` = `True` AppxPackages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily accomplished by the use of [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.1) to filter the resulting array:

```
Get-AppxPackage | Where-Object IsFramework
```

As opposed, if you wanted to filter where `IsFramework` is `$false`:

```
Get-AppxPackage | Where-Object IsFramework -EQ $false
```

Note that, here we're using **`Comparison statement`**, if you wanted to combine this expression with your previous question (filtering also, by those Apps **not in** `$WhitelistedApps`) you would need to filter using a **`Script block`**:

```
Get-AppxPackage | Where-Object { $_.IsFramework -and $_.Name -notin $WhitelistedApps }
```

Comment: As usual you helped me a lot, I wish you my sincere thanks for helping people solve their problems. You explained everything to me extensively. (What strengthens my PowerShell skills). It worked successfully! Best answer ☑️ I think I'll get a much better script than the Windows10Debloater on GitHub. xD

Comment: @Se7en hahaha thank you! happy to help and glad that you learnt something new with my answer

Comment: I hope both sides of your pillow are cold tonight ;)

Comment: @AbrahamZinala lol first time I see this English expression. Thanks :P

Comment: I've been trying so many combinations of Where and finally it worked by putting $ in front of false. Strange how sometimes powershell accepts it otherwise and keeps listing ones that had true.